# Java command that lists JAR files and associated paths (similar to Ruby's gem list -d)

Tags: java, jar, java-ws

The [Java TM API for XML Web Services](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.3/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) mentions using the Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism to substitute 2 JAR files (jaxws-api.jar and jaxb-api.jar) for the ones that are included in standard release of JDK 6.

Is there a console command that would prove that these JARs are being used instead of the ones that are included with the 'official' distribution?  Ideally, it would list the JAR name and directory.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM has an option to enable verbose logging.

- **verbose:class**
  Display information about each class loaded.
- **verbose:gc**
  Report on each garbage collection event.
- **verbose:jni**
  Report information about use of native methods and other Java Native    Interface activity.

That should help.

Regards